# Contagem de caracteres dentro de parágrafos distintos (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como utilizar o jQuery para fazer a soma de caracteres em diferentes parágrafos?
Exemplo:

```
<div id="test">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Obs. Não é possível adicionar `id` e `class` nas tags `<p>`.

Consegui fazer uma função ([aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/qcjnLbh7/)), mas ela utiliza o `.each()` do jQuery. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma outra maneira mais eficiente de resolver isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com JavaScript nativo usando um loop `for` e [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName):

```
var count = 0;
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    var text = ps[i].textContent || ps[i].innerText;
    count += text.length;
}
alert("count: " + count)
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eet9yp4q/

Se colocares isso no fim do `body` vai correr bem sem precisar de uma função a envolver.

Comment: Obrigado, Sergio.